# Print multiple documents continuously

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to implement a continious printing of document.Please see image below[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c87bde9396.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c87bde9396.png)

When I choose the checkboxes then click the print button, all the information of a particular applicant will be printed.Take note that each document was printed on a new page. I found a soluton from this forum http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/861073-print-multiple-files-continuously

But I need an additional resources about this to implement the best solution for this functionality.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best approach for this problem is to open a popup window with the contents using [page break](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks) when necessary. This way you have better control over what is printed and you can give user a chance to review what is going to be printed if you like or call `window.print` on ready.